# Spring Security 3.2 and servletApi()

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am trying to use `servletApi()` of Spring Security 3.2 M2 but could not be successful. `AuthenticationManager` seems null at `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter`. And because of this `HttpServlet3RequestFactory` is created with null `authenticationManager`.

Here is the implementation of my Security Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


   @Override
   protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      auth
         .inMemoryAuthentication()
         .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER")
         .and();
   }

   @Bean
   @Override
   public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean()  throws Exception {
      return super.authenticationManagerBean();
   }


   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
//         .exceptionHandling().and()
         .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ifRequired)
            .sessionRegistry(new StarSessionRegistry()).and().and()
         .securityContext().and()
//         .requestCache().and()
//         .anonymous().and()
         .servletApi().and()
//         .apply(new DefaultLoginPageConfigurer<HttpSecurity>()).and()
//         .logout()
//         .and()
         .authorizeUrls()
         .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
         .antMatchers("/**").authenticated();
   }
}
```

I can see that `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter` is enhanced by ObjectPostProcessor but seems that AuthenticationManager could not be injected inside it.

Do I need to provide another BeanProcessor or Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-2215

It was a bug and resolved for RC1.